# C++ Overload operator% for two doubles

Tags: c++, double, overloading, operator-keyword

is it possible to overload the `operator%` for two doubles?

```
const double operator%(const double& lhs, const double& rhs)
{
    return fmod(lhs, rhs);
}
```

Of course, this generates an error because one of the two parameters must have a class type.
So I thought about utilizing the possibility of implicit constructor calls of C++ to get around of this problem. I did it in the following way:

```
class MyDouble {
public:
    MyDouble(double val) : val_(val) {}
    ~MyDouble() {}

    double val() const { return val_; }

private:
    double val_;
};


const double operator%(const MyDouble& lhs, const double& rhs)
{
    return fmod(lhs.val(), rhs);
}

const double operator%(const double& lhs, const MyDouble& rhs)
{
    return fmod(lhs, rhs.val());
}
```

... and:

```
double a = 15.3;
double b = 6.7;

double res = a % b; // hopefully calling operator%(const MyDouble&, const double) using a implicit constructor call
```

Unfortunately, this does not work! Any hints, ideas, ... are appreciated!
Thanks in advance,
Jonas

Comment: hmm... why not simply call `fmod()` directly and not hack around with operator overloading where it's not necessary?

Answer (score 9):

The reason this doesn't work is because overload resolution for user defined operator functions is only triggered if at least one operand of the expression has a class or enumeration type.

So you are out of luck. This won't work.

I think the best you could try is waiting for a C++0x compiler and instead of writing `3.14`, you write `3.14_myd`, as a user defined literal.

Answer (score 0):

alternatively, implement `double MyDouble::operator%(const double&) const;`, like so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

class t_double {
public:
    t_double(const double& val) : d_val(val) {
    }

    t_double(const t_double& other) : d_val(other.d_val) {
    }

    ~t_double() {
    }

    const double& val() const {
        return this->d_val;
    }

    double operator%(const double& rhs) const {
        return fmod(this->val(), rhs);
    }

    double operator%(const t_double& rhs) const {
        return fmod(this->val(), rhs.val());
    }

private:
    double d_val;
};

int main(int argc, char* const argv[]) {

    const t_double a(15.3);
    const t_double b(6.7);

    std::cout << a % b << " == " << a.val() << " % " << b.val() << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I thought about this way, but I did not succeeded :( For a small example I would be very happy! Thanks!

Comment: Ok but the if you change const t_double a(15.3); to double a = 15.3; (for b too), then the code won't compile. And in the code I want to use not t_double but double.

Comment: it doesn't compile because you have to declare the free function: `double operator%(const double& lhs, const t_double& rhs) { return t_double(lhs) % rhs; }`

Comment: i had thought you had said `double a; t_double b; a % b` did not compile.

Comment: No, what I want is the following: double a = 14.3; double b = 11.23; double c = a % b;